# PTIJ: Passover blood and Bal Tashchis

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The other day I read that during the exodus the Jews were commanded to take the blood of the Pesach and schmear it ["on the two doorposts and the lentils, upon the houses wherein they shall eat it."](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0212.htm#7) (Ex. 12:7)

This seems to present a multitude of questions:

1. Aren't lentils technically kitniyot, making their use on Pesach forbidden according to "Minhag Yisroel KiHalacha?"
2. Why would Hashem command them to mix blood in their food and eat it - isn't eating blood forbidden?
3. If they were required to throw out the spoiled food, wouldn't this constitute a violation of bal tashchis (wanton destruction of food)?
4. What is the connection between the lentils and the doorposts - were the lentils supposed to be mixed with the blood and THEN schmeared on the doorposts?
5. How is this supposed to protect them from the final plague?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Seriously? why the downvote on a PTIJ question? if you've got a suggestion to improve the humor, please provide...

Comment: Downvotes on Purim Torah generally mean "not funny".

Comment: @Scimonster i understand that, hence the second half of my comment...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's not such a great pun.

Comment: Most good puns either are in the Hebrew word substituting for a similar word or transliterating a Hebrew word rather than translating it. This does neither but finds instead an English word that sounds the same as the real translation.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 1: This proves that we were all originally Sefardim. Thus we were allowed to [eat Kitniyot on Pesach](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/passover/pesach_cdo/aid/509460/jewish/Kitniyot.htm).

Regarding question 2: The verse is often mistranslated as blood. It says to take מִן-הַדָּם "MINADOM". MINADOM is actually a rare type of steak that is very tasty when eaten over a doorpost with lentils.

Regarding question 3: The verse says וְהַנֹּתָר מִמֶּנּוּ עַד-בֹּקֶר, בָּאֵשׁ תִּשְׂרֹפוּ which means anything left over in the morning has to be roasted in fire, not that it has to be wasted.

Regarding question 4 & 5: Those are too difficult to answer.